# Getting BSOD After When Trying To Print The Next Process Name In LIST_ENTRY List

Tags: c++, c, winapi, driver, winappdriver

I am trying to print the next process name after my process in the `LIST_ENTRY` list.
But I am always getting BSOD.

```
#include <Ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <WinDef.h>

void SampleUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    DbgPrint("Sample driver Unload called\n");
}


extern "C"
NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = SampleUnload;
    DbgPrint("Sample driver Load called\n");

    PEPROCESS EP;
    if (::PsLookupProcessByProcessId(::PsGetCurrentProcessId(), &EP) == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        DbgPrint("Can't get EPROCESS");
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    LIST_ENTRY list_entry = *((LIST_ENTRY*)(LPBYTE)EP + 0x448);
    UCHAR* fileName;
    fileName = ((UCHAR*)(LPBYTE)list_entry.Flink - 0x448 + 0x5a8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        DbgPrint("%u" , fileName[i]);

    DbgPrint("Finish");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the `EPROCESS` structure there is a `LIST_ENTRY` object in the `0x448` offset.
So I created a `LIST_ENTRY` object and assign him to the address of the `EPROCESS + 0x448` and than I add `0x5a8-0x448` to the `LIST_ENTRY.FLINK`.
That suppose to get to `ImageFileName` array in the `0x5a8` offset.

But It doesn't working from some reason.

Comment: Which code line triggers the BSOD?

Comment: I don't know, I am very in the driver world. How can I check?

Comment: Use the Kernel Debugger - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg--kernel-mode-

Comment: `*((LIST_ENTRY*)(LPBYTE)EP + 0x448);` You might try to add some brackets around `(LPBYTE)EP + 0x448` to ensure pointer arithmetics is done before the cast to `LIST_ENTRY*`

Comment: Now I am Getting Secure System in ascii. how can I convert that to string?

Comment: You mean you get `83 101 99 ...`? Is it nul-terminated? (I am not familiar with Windows internals) `UCHAR` is an `unsigned char`. That already looks very much like a string.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I get. I know that is supposed to be a string but it doesn't.

Comment: What does that mean "It doesn't"? You print each character as integer. You could also print as character with `"%c"` specifier or the whole string with `"%s"` if that array is nul-terminated

Comment: Bro you are the best thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple nonsensical casts in the code:

```
*((LIST_ENTRY*)(LPBYTE)EP + 0x448);
```

and

```
((UCHAR*)(LPBYTE)list_entry.Flink - 0x448 + 0x5a8);
```

This means for example convert `EP` (not the address of it) to a byte pointer, then (since casts have right-to-left associativity) immediately forget about converting to a byte pointer and instead convert to a `LIST_ENTRY*`. Then when done hesitating about which type to use, perform pointer arithmetic on `LIST_ENTRY` objects. That is `0x448 * sizeof(LIST_ENTRY)` bytes.

I guess you actually meant to do this:

```
LPBYTE lpb = (LPBYTE)&EP + 0x448;
LIST_ENTRY list_entry = *(LIST_ENTRY*)lpb;
```

That's possibly a strict aliasing violation bug though. Or an alignment bug.

Comment: only `(LPBYTE)EP + 0x448` without `&`. this of course nothing related to "strict aliasing violation", but all code in question nonsensical and full of errors

Comment: @tantan **1** `PsLookupProcessByProcessId(::PsGetCurrentProcessId())` - senseless. use `PsGetCurrentProcess`
**2** error checking for `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` is wrong
**3** `ObfDereferenceObject(EP)` not called
**4** use hard-coded offsets always wrong

Comment: Hey @RbMm , how can I avoid using hard-coded offsets?